# Unable to change the background color of the entire screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following component where I want to change the background of the whole application to "#080f26" color. However, the background color of the right and left sides of the screen does not change.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
} from "react-native";

export default class CitizenRegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          Keyboard.dismiss();
        }}
        activeOpacity={5}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor: "#080f26",
        }}
      >
        <SafeAreaView
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            paddingTop:
              Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight * 1.5 : 0,
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.regForm}>
            <View style={{ height: "20%", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <Image
                source={require("../gui_components/reportown.png")}
                style={{ width: "60%", height: "100%", resizeMode: "contain" }}
              />
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.header}>Register</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textinput}
              placeholder="Name"
              underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
              placeholderTextColor={"gray"}
            />
            ...
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  regForm: {
    backgroundColor: "#080f26",
  },
  ...
});
```

The screen is as follows:  [image]

How can I change the background color of the entire screen?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on  Expo snack -  https://snack.expo.dev/. It will give fellow devs easier wat to debug

Comment: give style={{flex:1 }} to the main tag

Comment: Yes give flex:1 to the main tag that is TouchableOpacity and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<SafeAreaView
  style={{
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      backgroundColor: "#080f26",
      paddingTop:
        Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight * 1.5 : 0,
  }}
>
```